# ants living in the phone company terminus/customer plug in weather-proof box

Tags: dsl-modem

Early this summer at the lake place I opened up their box (customer side) and ants were living with-in (both sides). Brushed them off and plugged in my DSL line. Service drops often, DSL line shows poor connectivity. Or at times everything is good except speed is only 11000 kb/980 kb. Did residue from ants mess it up?

Comment: ''...brushed them off'' Have you tried spraying the terminals with a cleaner? WD-40 can do wonders, then move the plug(s) on and off (in/out) to clear debris. Yes, ants can make quiet a mess. I would spray/powder around the whole box with ant killer. Hope this helped.

Comment: Speak to your ISP.